# access operators "[ ], ( ), { }" overloading in Fortran 90 or 2003

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading, fortran2003

Can I overload entry access operators [], () or {} for derived data types in FORTRAN 2003? In the following example, I want to define access scheme for the derived data type "custom".

```
type custom
   integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: a
end type custom

type(custom) :: t

! after some initialization 
! .....
! .....
! .....
!
t%a( (/ 1, 2, 5 /) ) ! return entries located in positions 1, 2, and 5
t{ (/ 1, 2, 5 /) }   ! ?????? I want to define what stuff it should return
```

How can I do that?

**Update:**

Note that I don't want to use the array "t%a" directly and do conventional sub-array operation on that. Instead, I want to redefine array operation for data type "custom" such that t{'first'} should return a pointer the first entry in t%a or t%a(1) so I can say

```
t['first']= 18
```

or

```
print *, t['first'].
```

Also with additional overloading I want to get a functionality like t[1] = 18 works like t['first'] = 18.

Comment: Note that the things you want to overload aren't operators in Fortran.

Comment: `() []` are not operators. `{}` is not in the Fortran character se at all(reserved for future use). Hence, they cannot be overloaded. Your syntax would also conflict with coarrays. Note it is quite sujective what is readable, my eyes see a coarray access in `a[1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rather depends on what you mean by "return".

By itself the example offered

```
t%a([1,2,5])   ! Using syntax offered by Fortran 2003
```

doesn't *return* anything: it's a *subobject*.  With a reference to that subobject we can do various things:

```
print *, t%a([1,2,5])
t%a([1,2,5]) = 27
t%a([1,2,5]) = sin(real(t%a([1,2,5])))
```

but there's still no concept of "returning".  Crucially, as we shall see, these are not expressions.

Coming to the question, can `t[]`, `t()`, `t{}` mean something, then the answer is, simply, "no".<sup>*</sup>  You may want, for example, to say:

```
t[1,2,5] = 1
```

to mean

```
t%a[1,2,5] = 1
```

but that is not something to consider.

It would be possible to create an expression like

```
print *, t%ref([1,2,5])
```

but we're quite in the non-definable territory.

However, as you now mention pointers, there's more to say.  Whilst the preferred syntax `t[1]` or `t["first"]` is not available we still have the option of type-bound procedures.  For example, a function call `t%ref("first")` may well be able to return a pointer to the first element of `t%a`.  For example, `t%ref(1)` could be like

```
module reference

  implicit none

  type custom
     integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: a
   contains
     procedure ref
  end type custom

contains

  function ref(t, idx)
    class(custom), target, intent(in) :: t
    integer, intent(in) :: idx
    integer, pointer :: ref

    ref => t%a(idx)
  end function ref

end module reference

  use reference
  implicit none

  type(custom), target :: t
  integer, pointer :: b

  t%a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  print *, t%a
  b => t%ref(1)  ! Fortran 2008 allows direct assignment
  b = 8          ! but compiler support is very limited.
  print *, t%a

end
```

If desired `ref` can be made generic so that `t%ref("first")` (etc.) is acceptable.

---

<sup>*</sup> I'm basing that on the fact that here `t` is a scalar.  However, as mentioned by Vladimir F in a comment `()` and `[]` potentially do mean things.  The first relates to arrays and the second to co-arrays.  Syntax, then, is an issue, but this answer looks more at the mechanism than syntax.

Comment: Thanks! By overloading I meant for example with either t['first'] or t[1] I get the first entry in array t%a. Or with t['last'] I get last entry. Note that for some reason I don't want to directly work with a reference to t%a. Can I do this kind of overloading?

Comment: The reason that I don't want to work with t%a directly is that in my code, "t%a" is a multidimensional and unstructured data type. I simplified it here to a one-dimensional integer array. So in general form I want to define exactly what kind of operation I want to do on "t%a" by simply using the wrapper data type "custom". like when I write "t[i,j] = value" it first goes and do some calculations to find where the entry (i,j) is in my complicated structure t%a and then return a pointer to it. This can significantly reduce the complexity of my code.

Comment: Thanks man! That's exactly what I wanted. I have done something similar in my code but I just wanted to double check and make sure that overloading HIGHLY READABLE things like [] {} are not available and hence we only have the choice of using bound procedure. Thanks again

Comment: also you can directly do lvalue assign like in your example t%ref(1) = 8 and there is no need for having variable "b". Just go grab the latest gcc-trunk and compile gfortran. They have recently implemented lvalue pointer assignments.

Comment: @argasm good to know, I must have missed this news on the gfortran mailing list.