# Overload subscript operator in Fortran

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading

I have some matrix type that can either be real or complex:

```
type t_mat
   logical :: is_real
   real    :: data_r(:,:)
   complex :: data_c(:,:)
end type
```

and I would like to overload the `=`-operator as well as the `(i,j)` operator, so that I could conveniently say:

```
type(t_mat) :: a

...

a(2,3) = 3
```

I know in C++ it is possible to overload the subscript operator. Does Fortran allow for something similar?

Comment: [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25587519/3157076) is slightly relevant.  You may find some ideas in it.

Comment: Note that `(...)` is not an operator in Fortran (and neither is `=`, but this can be "defined").

Comment: I think you need to explain what you want to achieve better.  If `a(2,3) = 3` is meant to select `a%data_r(2,3)`, no you cannot do that in Fortran.  First, `3` is an integer, which can be assigned to either a `REAL` or `COMPLEX` entity, so there is no way to unambiguously select `data_r` over `data_c`.  Second, you can have arrays of derived-type type.  This means that Fortran will see `a(2,3)` has an array reference.

Comment: The `is_real` switch determines whether the variable contains a real or a complex matrix and where the number is written.